# Navigation Bar Rounded Image in CSS

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm creating a navigation bar in CSS. The navigation bar has a background-image and I want the image to have rounded corners. I have already tried other things like `-moz` but nothing has worked so far. Here's my CSS:

```
ul{
    background-image: url(nav_bar.png); height: 60px;width: 35%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin:1;
    padding:0;
    left: 30%;
}
```

How can I give it rounded corners?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just change the image itself to have rounded corners rather than doing this 'after the fact' with CSS, as it is a non-repeating background image?

Comment: There are various js libraries which will help with cross-browser compatability

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-radius` along with `background-clipping: padding-box;`. Both properties need browser-specific prefixes unless you include something like [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/).

Your added CSS would look like:

```
ul {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /*increase the value to make it more round*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clipping: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-clipping: padding-box;
    background-clipping: padding-box;
}
```